# Validation output in a custom training loop not working - Tensorflow

Tags: tensorflow, keras, deep-learning

I am new to Deep Learning and I am trying to learn more about implementation in Tensorflow and Keras. I am basing my work on this link : https://www.tensorflow.org/guide/keras/writing_a_training_loop_from_scratch

1.) First I set up a fake data set, in batches of 10, as follows:

```
import tensorflow as tf
import numpy as np
from tensorflow.keras.layers import Dense, Input
from tensorflow.keras.losses import mean_squared_error
from tensorflow.keras import Model, optimizers

X = tf.random.shuffle(np.random.normal(size=500).reshape(-1,10,1))
Train_X = X[:30]
Val_X = X[30:40]
Test_X = X[40:50]
Y = 2*X + 2
Train_Y = Y[:30]
Val_Y = Y[30:40]
Test_Y = Y[40:50]
```

2.) Then I set up the model as follows:

```
inputs = tf.keras.Input(shape=(1,))
x = Dense(2, activation="relu", name="dense_1")(inputs)
x = Dense(2, activation="relu", name="dense_2")(x)
outputs = Dense(1, name="predictions")(x)
model = Model(inputs=inputs, outputs=outputs)

optimizer = optimizers.SGD(learning_rate=1e-3)
loss_fn =mean_squared_error
```

3.) I set up my custom loop as follows:

```
epochs = 10

for epoch in range(epochs):

    for step, (x_batch_train, y_batch_train) in enumerate(zip(Train_X, Train_Y)):
        with tf.GradientTape() as tape:
        predictions = model(x_batch_train, training=True)
        loss_value = loss_fn(y_batch_train, predictions)
    grads = tape.gradient(loss_value, model.trainable_weights)
    optimizer.apply_gradients(zip(grads, model.trainable_weights))
    #print(grads)

    for step, (x_batch_val, y_batch_val) in enumerate(zip(Val_X, Val_Y)):
        val_predictions = model(x_batch_val, training=False)
        print('Valuation predictions for the batch :')
        print(val_predictions)
        print('Actual Valuation for the batch :')
        print(y_batch_val)
```

I wanted to double check the progress the model was making by looking at the validation predictions I get, like this :

```
Start of epoch 7
Valuation predictions for the batch :
tf.Tensor(
[[1.9706799]
 [1.9706799]
 [1.9706799]
 [1.9706799]
 [1.9706799]
 [1.9706799]
 [1.9706799]
 [1.9706799]
 [1.9706799]
 [1.9706799]], shape=(10, 1), dtype=float32)
Actual Valuation for the batch :
tf.Tensor(
[[ 0.46222022]
 [ 4.14915307]
 [-0.4027977 ]
 [ 5.86534374]
 [ 2.4339228 ]
 [ 4.09712344]
 [ 2.68675164]
 [ 1.1638311 ]
 [ 1.898602  ]
 [ 2.630972  ]], shape=(10, 1), dtype=float64)
Valuation predictions for the batch :
tf.Tensor(
[[1.9706799]
 [1.9706799]
 [1.9706799]
 [1.9706799]
 [1.9706799]
 [1.9706799]
 [1.9706799]
 [1.9706799]
 [1.9706799]
 [1.9706799]], shape=(10, 1), dtype=float32)
Actual Valuation for the batch :
tf.Tensor(
[[ 2.23510644]
 [ 0.26278813]
 [ 1.89419175]
 [ 2.56711307]
 [-0.56344412]
 [-0.22523397]
 [ 1.81370046]
 [ 0.70580016]
 [ 3.81906033]
 [ 4.39636782]], shape=(10, 1), dtype=float64)
```

So regardless of the values of the valuation data set, my model always predicts the same thing. Any help would be fully appreciated in understanding why this happens.

Answer (score 0):

a couple of things I noticed:

1. Tensorflow works by default with float32 and not float64, but you feed your network with float64. This generates no problem here, but I would make sure to hard-code your dtype.
2. Your indentations are wrong. This is correct:

```
epochs = 10
for epoch in range(epochs):

for step, (x_batch_train, y_batch_train) in enumerate(zip(Train_X, Train_Y)):
    with tf.GradientTape() as tape:
        predictions = model(x_batch_train, training=True)
        loss_value = loss_fn(y_batch_train, predictions)
    grads = tape.gradient(loss_value, model.trainable_weights)
    optimizer.apply_gradients(zip(grads, model.trainable_weights))
```

Good luck for your future work!